# Error while trying to install wine 1.3

Tags: wine, apt, keyserver

Am I doing something wrong?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /etc/apt/secring.gpg --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 883E8688397576B6C509DF495A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
gpg: requesting key F9CB8DB0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah: communicating with key servers uses a different port.

See: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9484262

Answer (score 0):

You can install Wine 1.3 beta using the Ubuntu Software Centre.